# Java: Converting an input of seconds into hours/minutes/seconds

Tags: java, math

This is an exercise question taken from *Java Software Solutions: foundations of program design* by Lewis & Loftus, 4th edition ; Question PP2.6 (here is a [link](http://mimoza.marmara.edu.tr/~odemir/Java%20Software%20Solutions%20-%20Foundations%20of%20Program%20Design%20(4th%20Edition).pdf))

**Question is as follows:** " Create a project that reads a value representing a number of seconds, then print the equivalent amount of time as a combination of
hours, minutes, and seconds. (For example, 9999 seconds is equivalent
to 2 hours, 46 minutes, and 39 seconds.)"

I have so far tried the following

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double totalSecs, seconds, minutes, hours;

    System.out.println("Enter number of seconds: ");

    totalSecs = scan.nextInt();

    hours = totalSecs/3600;
    minutes = (Math.abs(Math.round(hours)-hours))*60;
    seconds = (Math.abs(Math.round(minutes)-minutes))*60;

    System.out.print(hours + "\n" + minutes + "\n" + seconds);

}
```

Answer came out to,
*hours: 2.7775* 
*minutes: 13.350000000000009* 
*seconds: 21.00000000000051*

What I want to do is take the decimals of, say, hours and multiply them by 60 to get minutes and repeat the process for seconds. I'm however having trouble figuring it out, hence the messy solution of (Math.abs) etc.

What would you recommend me to change/add? Thanks!

Note: This is a book for beginners, hence I've not learned many more operations than those I've already stated in the code. As such, I haven't understood the solution for the previous times this question has been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way of doing it:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(sf.format(new Date(9999000)));
}
```

**Note:** Please note that this will only show the output in 24-hour format and if number of hours is greater than 24 then it'll increment a day and will start over. For example, 30 hours will be displayed as `06:xx:xx`. Also, you'll have to pass the input in milliseconds instead of seconds.

If you want to do it your way then you should probably do something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    long input = 9999;
    long hours = (input - input%3600)/3600;
    long minutes = (input%3600 - input%3600%60)/60;
    long seconds = input%3600%60;
    System.out.println("Hours: " + hours + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " + seconds);
}
```

Output:

```
Hours: 2 Minutes: 46 Seconds: 39
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was aiming at trying to solve the question with the methods I already know. The SimpleDateFormat is nothing I've encountered, but thanks for showing it to me!
EDIT: Your edit answer is more of what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @user2004685 First of your example gives 04:46:39 as result, is it true? or because of locale, timezone etc?

Comment: @YusufK. Yes, that is because of the TimeZone. You'll have to set it to `GMT`.

Comment: @user2004685  And What will be result if seconds will be 119999000, With SimpleDateFormat, hour is never bigger than 12, if use HH instead hh, it is never bigger than 23

Comment: @YusufK. Yes, you are right. `HH` will display it in 24-hour format. Alternatively, you can use `AM/PM` also. Depend on the needs.

Comment: @user2004685 But there is one more exception which is about to take  output as 30 hours  25 minutes and 30 seconds (countdown). SimpleDateFormat will never give that result. So I think that should be specified on your answer

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative of [user2004685](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004685/user2004685)'s answer;

```
int seconds = 9999; 
int hour = 9999 / (60 * 60); //int variables holds only integer so hour will be 2
seconds = 9999 % (60 * 60); // use modulo to take seconds without hours so it will be 2799
int minute = seconds / 60; //same as int variable so minute will be 49
seconds = seconds % 60; // modulo again to take only seconds
System.out.println(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering it in a similar way to how I wrote it (except for the modulo), as I was aiming at solving it with the knowledge I already have.

Comment: @Newman You're welcome, if you are trying to make a countdown program, SimpleDateFromat will not work as expected(for bigger values than 24 hour). So you should calculate as answered.